# Unexpected result when compiling Sass files in October CMS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, octobercms

1. I use `<link href="{{['assets/sass/rapido.scss']|theme}}" rel="stylesheet">`
2. rapido.scss (master stylesheet) imports all required styles:

```
@import "settings";
@import "overrides";
@import "../vendor/rfs/scss";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "fonts";
...
@import "footer";
@import "keyframes";
```

2. I've set `'enableAssetDeepHashing' => true in config/cms.php`
3. The structure of my assets directory is:

```
sass
  ├── _header.scss
  ├── _footer.scss
  ├── ...
  └── rapido.scss
vendor
   ├── bootstrap
           ├── scss
                 ├── mixins
                 ├── utilities
                 ├── vendor
                 ├── _grid.scss
                 ├── _toasts.scss
                 ├── ...
                 ├── bootstrap.scss
   ├── rfs
        ├── scss.scss
```

**Issues**

1. Looking at the compiled CSS, the `.container` class, has no `max-width` set to it, at each responsive breakpoint. I don't have this problem when using `gulp-sass` on my static implementation.
2. The responsive font sizes (rfs/scss.scss) mixins don't work.
   The following:

```
.space-py-8 {
    @include padding-top(8rem);
    @include padding-bottom(8rem);
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.space-py-8 {
    padding-top: if(type-of($values) != list, ($values,), $values);
    padding-bottom: if(type-of($values) != list, ($values,), $values);
}
```

And this:

```
body {
    @include font-size(1rem);
}
```

Compiles to:

```
body {
    font-size: if(type-of($values) != list, ($values,), $values);
}
```

Again, I don't have this problem when using `gulp-sass` on my static implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to v1.1.1, there were a number of SASS compilation issues that were fixed in v1.1 by switching to a different dependency to handle the compilation because the one that was in use had been abandoned.

Comment: I was about to release a theme on the October CMS marketplace, and I've encountered those SASS compilation issues. Should I wait until the v.1.1.1 comes out to release theme?

As for updating to test version v.1.1.1 could you please provide a bit more information (or a link) on how to do it?

Should I follow the installation guide here: https://packagist.org/packages/october/october.

Comment: If you want to release it on the marketplace then you should probably wait until the 1.1.1 update is available on the marketplace. As far as testing 1.1.1 right now goes, follow the instructions in https://github.com/octoberrain/meta/blob/master/l6-upgrade-notes.md

Comment: Thank you so much.